# Matrix Exponential of Identity Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation

I was just wondering what would the sum be of $e^{I_n}$ where $I_n$ is the identity matrix. I know the maclaurin series for $e^x$ is $1+\frac x{1!}+\frac {x^2}{2!}+...$. I know that $e^0$ is 1 right? How should I calculate $e^{I_n}$

Comment: $\displaystyle \exp(M) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{M^{n}}{n!}$ for all square matrix $M$. If $M=\mathrm{I}_{n}$, $M^n$ is quite easy to compute...

Comment: How would i solve sum of In/n! without a calculator?

Comment: As with all identities, $In^k=In$ for all $k$

Comment: $\displaystyle \exp(\mathrm{I}_{n}) = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{I}_{n}}{k!} = \Big( \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \Big) \mathrm{I}_{n}$

Comment: In what applications is the identity matrix exponential even useful?

Comment: It's very useful in quantum computing.  see e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/164109/dealing-with-tensor-products-in-an-exponent

Answer (score 10):

You can use the Taylor expansion of the exponential,

$\displaystyle e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$.

All the powers of the identity matrix are equal to the identity matrix, so $\displaystyle I_n^k = I_n$.

Therefore,

$\displaystyle e^{I_n} = I_n \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} = e \, I_n$.

This is a diagonal matrix with all the terms in the diagonal being $e$.

Answer (score 2):

For a diagonal matrix $M$ the exponential is simply the exponential of each diagonal entry: $$e^M=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
e^{m_{11}} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & e^{m_{22}} & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & e^{m_{nn}} \end{array}\right).$$
You can show this from the identity
$$e^M = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} M^k.$$
Since the product of two diagonal matrices $A$ and $B$ is the product of their diagonal elements,
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & a_{22} & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{nn} \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
b_{11} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & b_{22} & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & b_{nn} \end{array}\right)
=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11}b_{11} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & a_{22}b_{22} & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{nn}b_{nn} \end{array}\right),$$
it easily follows that $e^M$ is as shown above.

Comment: oh ok so since the identity matrix is a diagonal matrix you can just multiply e^A in?

Comment: Yes, in the particular case $e^I$ the result is a diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries $e$.